# How to create objects dynamically from json string in C#?

Tags: json, c#-4.0, dynamicobject

I am new to C# programming. I am getting a Json string as input, How can I create a dynamic objects from json strings and access the values from object. My Json string structure is not constant, Hence, I cannot go with predefined class structure.

My sample Json string would be :

```
 {"Var":[
    {"Var1":{"Var2":{"Var3":[{"Var4":"var5", "var6":{
        "Var5":"val11",
        "Var6":"val22",
        "Var7":"val33"}},
        {"Var4":"var5", "var6":{
        "Var5":"val11",
        "Var6":"val22"}
        },
        {"Var4":"var5", "var6":{
        "Var5":"val11",
        "Var6":"val22",
        "Var7":"val33"}
        },
        {"Var4":"var5", "var6":{
        "Var5":"val11"}
        }
        ]
      }
     }}
    ]}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think below link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object

Comment: Thanks Buddy ... I was able to achieve my goal ... :)